# Calling multiple httpclient that contain two different base address

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I have read up on [named clients and typed clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#typed-clients) in order to achieve my ultimate goal. However, I still do not understand how I need to implement either or. I have a blazor server side project that in the startup.cs file I have it set up as

`services.AddSingleton(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:36626") });`

`services.AddSingleton(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5443") });`

I know that if I do this, the baseaddress of the first one will completely be overwritten and no longer be the set base address due to the second baseaddress. **How would I go about making this work so that way I have two separate httpclients that will have two separate baseaddress without having to lose one because of the most recent line of code?**

Comment: Have you tried the examples in that link? They don't use `services.AddSingleton` but `services.AddHttpClient("github"...` or `services.AddHttpClient<RepoService>(c => ...`. It's difficult to figure out what you're looking for in an answer that's not already explained in the examples in the docs

Comment: The thing I am confused is that either or will have `c.baseaddress = new uri("github.com)"`  so what I want is to have two separate base addresses one for port `36626` and another for port `5443`... would I need to have it as `c.baseaddress= new(localhost:36626)` and after that line have `c.baseaddrss=(localhost:5443)`?

Comment: I don't understand why you would want two identical HTTP clients with different base addresses, but you can always resolve IEnumerable<HttpClient> or IEnumerable<MyTypedHttpClient> to get an enumerable of all registered implementations of those service types - the second registration does not "overwrite" the first, it just becomes the default.

Comment: I understand, thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the doc, the main differences are in how you are going to get an instance through Dependency Injection.

With **Named Client** you need to inject the factory and then get the client by a string.

```
var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("github");
```

With **Typed Client** you can inject the client needed as a type.

```
//GitHubService encapsulate an HTTP client
public TypedClientModel(GitHubService gitHubService)
    {
        _gitHubService = gitHubService;
    }
```

Both of them give the solution to your problem. The selection is more in how comfortable you are with the dependency injection method of each one. I personally prefer the Typed client.

Comment: Sorry I am still confused because on the document, the base address is only set for one and not two different base addresses. Do not see how typed or named clients can handle two different base addresses... would I need to call them both inside either named/typed clients?

Comment: First `HttpClient ` is not singleton, is transient, that means there is a different object instance on each injection. 
So when you use a Typed, you create and configure a class **TypedHttpClient**, then  the configuration of the internal `HttpClient ` have no effect in the configuration in other instance of the class.

Follow [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#typed-clients-1), it is very clear.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!